# Procurar e-mail ou palavra dentro de um site com selenium webdriver no python?

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver

Olá,

estou querendo criar um Bot para entrar em um site e procurar se aquele site possui um email para contato e criar uma lista de emails ... o problema é que isso tudo pode ser muito genérico.. em algum site pode estar em um id, em outro pode estar em class ... pensei em tentar ler todos elementos HTML do site e verificar se possui texto com "@" e ".COM" para caracterizar como um email ... porem estou vindo do VBA para o python e ainda estou apanhando ... na documentação do selenium ele mostra um exemplo que busca uma palavra dentro da pagina, mas quando eu rodo ele da erro na importação do "PAGE" ... alguem poderia me ajudar com um código para ler todos elementos HTML e procurar uma palavra ou me ajudar a resolver essa questão do import Page, pois procurando no google não encontrei nada se esse page já vem instalado no Selenium ou se eu tenho que instalar, qual o PIP INSTALL eu tenho que usar e etc ...

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver

import page

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):
    """A sample test class to show how page object works"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("http://www.python.org")

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        """
        Tests python.org search feature. Searches for the word "pycon" then verified that some results show up.
        Note that it does not look for any particular text in search results page. This test verifies that
        the results were not empty.
        """

        #Load the main page. In this case the home page of Python.org.
        main_page = page.MainPage(self.driver)
        #Checks if the word "Python" is in title
        assert main_page.is_title_matches(), "python.org title doesn't match."
        #Sets the text of search textbox to "pycon"
        main_page.search_text_element = "pycon"
        main_page.click_go_button()
        search_results_page = page.SearchResultsPage(self.driver)
        #Verifies that the results page is not empty
        assert search_results_page.is_results_found(), "No results found."

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breno, fui procurar esse tutorial que você iniciou, ao que parece você pulou a leitura da sessão **6.2**, ela explica como criar o **page**.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html

```py
import page
```

O código acima esta tentando importar uma classe que ainda não existe, por isso esta dando erro.

Sobre como achar um elemento que contenha o **@** e termine com **.com**, isso sera possível usando Xpath e o método findElement.

Exemplo buscando um elemento qualquer que *contenha* **@python.org**:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'@python.org')]")
```

Exemplo buscando um elemento qualquer que *termine* com **@python.org**:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('@python.org') + 1) = '@python.org']")
```

Exemplo buscando um elemento qualquer que *contenha* **@** e *termine* com **.org**:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'@') and substring(text(), string-length(text()) - string-length('.org') +1) = '.org']")
```

Comment: Funcionou Perfeitamente ... Muito Obrigado !